# What are the best SEO techniques for a professional blog?

Tags: seo, wordpress, blog, meta-keywords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

Beginner to SEO here, starting with a personal site, looking for some insight and feedback.

Question: what's more important, domain name or site title?

Question: how important are the meta tags (description and keywords) on your site?  Description should be under 60 chars right?  How many keywords is ideal?

Question: #1 most important SEO principle = ?? (my guess is getting others to link to your site)

-thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### #1 Most Important SEO Principle:

Good, relevant and frequently updated content. Everything else is secondary.